# How to run mysql Sp in asp.net using Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq, stored-procedures

I have created Sp in Mysql

```
    CREATE  PROCEDURE data1(IN pid INT) 
        select * from data where id=pid
```

where i have data table in which there are 2 column id and no

### id  | no

and now i want to call that Sp in ASP.NET using EF

```
 var a = db.data1(10);
```

when i am running sp in mysql it is giving  me an output which is perfect 
but when i am using SP in asp.net then every time a is storing 0 
and it is not returning any result .

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures             Maybe this will help

Comment: @Yagzii The OP is using EF, not Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: db is my context object

Answer (score 0):

A bit too hard to read through your code. Have you actually added the sprocs to your model? If not, that is where I would go first. Here is a good basic read on using sprocs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: now  i have added the simple sp but still the condition is same  i am not getting the op